# Metrics of SURF detector in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

I follow my example link which is find matching points between original image and query image to detect is that query image is in original image or not

when use template ( query image )is in original image work fine , when use query image there is not found in original image appear this problem

that problem is when there is :

```
MATCHED_POINTS1 ( original image ) and MATCHED_POINTS2 ( query image )
do not contain enough points
```

and

```
Error using affine2d/set.T 
The final column of an affine transformation matrix must consist of zeroes,
except for a one in the last row.
```

Q : I need to find a metric that count matching points percentage because when applying geometric transform return error due there are no enough matching points ..?

my example link as follow http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html

Comment: you seem to be getting this error because you are expecting a number of feature points from your query image, but not enough feature points are found in your original image (since the query image is not in the original). As we have no idea how your code works specifically, I can only say that you need a step to determine if the query image is actually in the original. You can try to set a threshold on the percentage of matching features, but this can still cause errors in certain cases.

Comment: thank you sir ,,, how can get or set a percentage of matching features ... any idea please

Comment: can you try to set different number of feature points to both the original image and the query image, where the number of feature points for the original image should be significantly greater? See if any of these numbers will actually avoid the error. The thing is, you are using the toolbox, so you should avoid changing what is in the toolbox; but you also need a way around it, my guess is that you might be able to go around it by designing an algorithm that changes the number of feature points.

Comment: sir i can count the matching points but for different query images return different numbers of points some 300 and some 8 or 10 ,,, etc but in both cases treat as one when apply geometric transform i got error for small points found ,,, can you help me to detect is that query image is in original before apply geometric transform ...

Comment: so if the original image returns less matched feature points than the query image, then it will cause errors. You should compare your matching points (300, 8 or 10) with the number of feature points in the original image (say, 300), if 8/300 is less than a certain threshold (say 40%), the image does not exist in the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you are getting is thrown by `estimateGeometricTransform`. You need at least 3 matched pairs of points to estimate the affine transformation. If `matchedBoxPoints` and `matchedScenePoints` contain less than 3 points, then you will get this error. You can simply check what `size(boxPairs, 1)` is. If it is less than 3, you can conclude that the object is not present in the scene.

Comment: thanks ... this work fine to me and give great result .... 
there are some useful properties in the following link ... how we can use one of them if possible : 

http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.geometrictransformestimator-class.html